# Android Clear Cache

Tags: java, android, xml, caching

I want to click on the preference is cleared the cache of my app. I did this, but it does not work and there are errors. How can I fix?

This is the whole source. Many Thanks!!!!!!

```
public class Impo extends PreferenceActivity{


Preference info;
Intent intent;
Preference cache;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.layout);


info= (Preference) this.findPreference("info");
info.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Info.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }});
cache = (Preference)this.findPreference("cache");
cache.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

}
}
public static void clearCache(final Context context)
{
final File cache=context.getCacheDir();
final File appDir=new File(cache.getParent());
if(appDir.exists())
  {
  // you might be able to change this whole code block to just "deleteDir(appDir)"
  final String[] children=appDir.list();
  for(final String childFilePath : children)
    if(!childFilePath.equals("lib"))
      {
      deleteDir(new File(appDir,childFilePath));
      Log.i("TAG","**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/"+childFilePath+" DELETED *******************");
      }
  }
}

public static boolean deleteDir(final File dir)
{
if(dir==null)
  return true;
if(dir.isDirectory())
  {
  final String[] children=dir.list();
  for(final String childFilePath : children)
    {
    final boolean success=deleteDir(new File(dir,childFilePath));
    if(!success)
      return false;
    }
  }
return dir.delete();
}
}
```

.......................................

Comment: "it does not work and there are errors". So, tell us what errors you get, tell us what your calls to Log show, tell us what isn't working.

Comment: okay. eclipse marks mistake here File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());, here }, here public static boolean deleteDir(File dir),and here if (dir != null &amp;&amp; dir.isDirectory()) {

Comment: do you import the File class?

Comment: Yes. I'm going crazy. Help me please :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my suggestion of how to fix your errors.

i could make it even better, but it should work just fine.

```
cache.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
  {
  clearCache(getApplicationContext());
  }
```

and here are the functions , fixed:

```
public static void clearCache(final Context context)
  {
  final File cache=context.getCacheDir();
  final File appDir=new File(cache.getParent());
  if(appDir.exists())
    {
    // you might be able to change this whole code block to just "deleteDir(appDir)"
    final String[] children=appDir.list();
    for(final String childFilePath : children)
      if(!childFilePath.equals("lib"))
        {
        deleteDir(new File(appDir,childFilePath));
        Log.i("TAG","**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/"+childFilePath+" DELETED *******************");
        }
    }
  }

public static boolean deleteDir(final File dir)
  {
  if(dir==null)
    return true;
  if(dir.isDirectory())
    {
    final String[] children=dir.list();
    for(final String childFilePath : children)
      {
      final boolean success=deleteDir(new File(dir,childFilePath));
      if(!success)
        return false;
      }
    }
  return dir.delete();
  }
```

---

here's the entire class code :

```
public class Impo extends PreferenceActivity {

    Preference info;
    Intent intent;
    Preference cache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.layout);

        info = this.findPreference("info");
        info.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {
                // TODO the next line is very weird. sure that's what you want?
                intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Info.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        });
        cache = this.findPreference("cache");
        cache.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(final Preference preference) {
                clearCache(Impo.this);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    public static void clearCache(final Context context) {
        final File cache = context.getCacheDir();
        final File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
        if (appDir.exists()) {
            // you might be able to change this whole code block to just "deleteDir(appDir)"
            final String[] children = appDir.list();
            for (final String childFilePath : children)
                if (!childFilePath.equals("lib")) {
                    deleteDir(new File(appDir, childFilePath));
                    Log.i("TAG", "**************** File /data/data/APP_PACKAGE/" + childFilePath
                            + " DELETED *******************");
                }
        }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(final File dir) {
        if (dir == null)
            return true;
        if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            final String[] children = dir.list();
            for (final String childFilePath : children) {
                final boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, childFilePath));
                if (!success)
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return dir.delete();
    }
}
```

Comment: i've written functions. functions cannot be written inside other functions. please put "}" in the correct places, and then check it out again. also, what you've shown doesn't show the errors, only their markers. the errors are written in the "problems" view of eclipse (use ALT+SHIFT+Q,X to show it). i've edited my answer again so that you see they are separated .

Comment: I put out the works but an error is here clearCache(getApplicationContext());
Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  ConstructorDeclaration

Comment: your code won't compile , not because of the functions i've written, but because the location you've written there in. look at the lines after "cache.setOnPreferenceClickListener" - instead of implementing the interface you've put there the functions i've written. again, they should be outside of any method or function. they are not supposed to be where you've put them.

Comment: I have tried in many ways but eclipse report always errors. Could you help me, posting Magati the right code?

Comment: what's magati? please post the whole code and i will fix it, but you have to learn how to read your code. this is a very basic thing. maybe you should watch "the new boston" series for learning java: http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=31

Comment: Thank you very much. The entire code is in the initial question.

Comment: updated answer. please read it and understand what is going on. there is also a weird line that i haven't changed since i don't know its purpose, but i've written about it as a comment.

Comment: Many Thanks!!! It works perfectly! Last question. Why if i put a toast in public static boolean deleteDir(final File dir) give me an error? I have put Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "MY TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); Thanks again

Comment: @Giannirossi that's because i've made the function to be static. if you wish , you can remove the "static" keyword from both of the functions. however, since those operations are not really related to UI, i would advice to use a mechanism to tell whoever has called the functions about what was done. you can also use the logs if you just need to make some tests.

Comment: again, please read more about java. those things are not related to android. it's basic java knowledge. i recommend watching "the new boston" videos. they also have videos for android development.